# Codeigniter - Recover ID?

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert

I need to retrieve the last ID inserted in a table and pass this ID to the field of another function

***Recover ID this way is possible ?***

```
$negociacao = array(
            'id'             => $neg->id,
            'dt_negociacao'  => $neg->dt_negociacao,
            'atualizar'      => $neg->atualizar,
            'contrato_id'    => $neg->contrato_id,
            'id_finalizacao' => $neg->id_finalizacao,
            'crud'           => "C",
        );
    $this->db->insert('tbl_devedor_negociacao', $negociacao);
    $negociacao_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id);

// set ID
private function set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id = null)
{       
    return $negociacao_id;
}

// get ID
private function get_negociacao_id()
{
    $this->set_negociacao_id();
}

// Assign retrieved ID here
'negociacao_id'  => $this->set_negociacao_id(),
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting correct inserted ID. But issue with `getter` and `setter` change it as below

```
// set ID
private function set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id = null)
{       
    $this->negociacao_id = $negociacao_id;
}

// get ID
private function get_negociacao_id()
{
    return $this->negociacao_id;
}

// Assign retrieved ID here
'negociacao_id'  => $this->get_negociacao_id(),
```

Comment: Did not work this way.

echo in $negociacao_id is OK.

But, return is null

Comment: will you show your entire code? (Insertion and use id of another function)

Answer (score 1):

***So solved***

```
// Setter ID negociacao
private $negociacao_id;
private function set_negociacao_id($negociacao_id)
{
    $this->negociacao_id = $negociacao_id;
}   
// Getter ID negociacao
private function get_negociacao_id()
{
    return $this->negociacao_id;
}


'negociacao_id'  => $this->get_negociacao_id(),
```

Comment: This is what exactly I have suggest you